# Which verb does this 'that-clause' serve as the object of?

Tags: sentence-structure

This is from [a news article](https://www.theverge.com/2023/6/15/23762501/reddit-ceo-steve-huffman-interview-protests-blackout) :

> Huffman now takes issue with the third-party apps that are building a
> business on top of his own. “I didn’t know — and this is my fault —
> the extent that they were profiting off of our API. **That these were
> not charities.**”

I wonder which verb '**That these were not charities**' serves as the object of?

I looked up 'that' in the M-W dictionary([conjunction 1b](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/that#dictionary-entry-2)).

Or is the "**That**" in the quote this 'that'?

> used as a function word to introduce an exclamatory clause expressing
> a strong emotion especially of surprise, sorrow, or indignation
>
> *that it should come to this!*

Comment: It's poorly written, though the _that_ clause is not an object but a declarative content clause functioning as an adjunct or arguably as a complement of"know". Note that _that_ clauses are predominantly complements of some verb, noun etc., or possibly adjuncts, but never objects.

Comment: @BillJ Sorry. I just edited the original post. Thank you very much.

Comment: It's not an excalamatory clause. There's a punctuation error in the transcription of the quote. "That" should NOT begin a new sentence. There should be a comma after API. If you simplify the quote, and fix the error, you can see the construction better: "I didn't know  . . .  that these were not charities".

Comment: @BillyKerr Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I read the text as reported speech, and *That these were charities* seems to refer simply to *I didn't know*.

An alternative wording could have been:

> “I didn’t know — and this is my fault — the extent that they were profiting off of our API. I didn't know that these were not charities.”

Although not an optimal example of stylistic writing, this is a very common thing in spoken language, for example:

> I wasn't aware that she didn't have a job. That she couldn't afford that new car.

As a side note, as @BillJ mentions in a comment under the question, the text seems poorly written. However, what we are looking at is reported speech, in which case I think it is better to report what was said than change someone's words because of stylistic considerations. As a spoken text, this seems totally natural.

Comment: Thank you very much.